# Updating or Fetching Big Data from Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, bigdata, etl

I have around 1.9m record in Mongodb collection `leads`. Sample document is below:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60174f6cc3"
  },
  "customer_id": "590583",
  "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "firstname": "XYZ",
  "mobile": "234567876",
  "newsletter": "1",
  "verified_email": "0",
  "verified_mobile": "1",
  "luid": "0zmapjn1-ij3h-aq-jifg-x0w3lvkkm8mbzx",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-02-01T07:46:08.000Z"
  },
  "modifiedAt": {
    "$date": "2022-08-01T09:39:15.000Z"
  },
  "identifiedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-02-01T08:01:32.201Z"
  },
  "segments": [
    "64ec38d66794a663c71fb7c1"
  ]
}
```

I am creating user segments based on user's behaviour. and storing segment id in list of user's doc as above.

Now, When i create a campaign, i am fetching all doc matching segment id and then dump them  in `campaignAudience` collection.

In case of small audience, it works, but if total reachable audience in segment is big like 800,000 or 120,0000 or more, then fetching and storing in campaignAudience takes too much time or i get timeout error.

What could be the best approach to do this work. should i consider Spark, Hadoop or something else.

**I am using Django 3.2 and MongoDB hosted on AWS EC2**

I tried threading for storing but still fetching a big data is causing problem. I wish i could fetch small batches and dump in destinition collection. but this cud be slow in process.

Comment: Have you identified the bottleneck of your operation? Is the fetching documents by segment id slow or storing to new collection slow? If it is the former, have your try indexing the `segments` field to speed up the query?

Comment: fetching is fast as i created index on segment and also I am fetching by using $skip and $limit for batching. due to huge amount of data, insertion is slow. i am using 5 threads as well...